# Postman can't connect .net core app hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, https, proxy, postman, http-proxy

I am getting this error when opening path https://localhost/app/page

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:433
Postman-Token: 64a1754f-04da-4edf-a2b6-9bc7f86d9b7c
```

As some articles recommend I set the Postman proxy settings off. The Windows Proxy settings are also set off. I have tried the following too:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=
set http_proxy=
set HTTPS_PROXY=
set https_proxy=
START %LOCALAPPDATA%\Postman\Update.exe --processStart "Postman.exe"
```

But getting the same error.

The path above **can be** successfully opened in Chrome.

Comment: `https://localhost/app/page` links to `127.0.0.1:433`? Are you certain you copied the information correctly?

Comment: @LexLi yes. i also found that Postman is not capable of connecting the websites with HSHT. I do use HSHT in my app.

Comment: however, there's anonter net6 app hosted in IIS that doens't use HTSH and Postman can't connect it either.